# How can I add the Post ID to Class Name in Jquery?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, css, html

In the custom Wordpress theme archive page, I will have Sharing icons for all the posts. Below is the HTML for showing Sharing icon:

```
<span id="post-share-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-share">
            // show sharing icons here
        </span>
        <span id="share-icon-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="share-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
```

Once the sharing icon is clicked in `#share-icon`, sharing icons will be shown from `#post-share`.
The challenge is sharing icon is clicked anywhere, the first post is showing the icons.

So, I have added `<?php the_ID(); ?>` to have unique classes. Now all the sharing icons has unique post ID's; however in jQuery I am not able to get this unique ID's.
Below is the jQuery to correct for this function to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#post-share" + (postID here)).hide();
$('#share-icon' + postID here).click(function () {
    $('#post-share' + postID here).show();
});
});
```

Help required is to add the post ID's to the class names in jQuery.

Comment: IF you have having issues with the ID attribute, why dont you try to use the data-attribute. That can help you a lot and you would not have to split anything as well

Answer (score 0):

You are using css to display none we don't need to use show() function.

Please  click on javascript icon in fiddle and select any jquery1.9.1 or above version .  Update this code and run (  http://screenshotlink.ru/8f491216a33e437f762eb8815efec77d.png )

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.share-icon').on('click',function (e) {
       var id = $(this).attr("id").split('-'); 
      $('.post-share#post-share-'+id[2]).css("display","block");
   });

});
```

Comment: It did not worked; I have created jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/4Lsmbu4s/)

Comment: try now above code